# How to create a paginator?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I've checked out the rather thin [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination), but still unsure how to do this.

I have a collection. I wish to manually create a paginator.

I think I have to do something like, in my controller:

```
new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator()
```

But, what params do I need and do I need to slice the collection? Also how do I then display the 'links' in my view?

Could someone post a simple example how to create a paginator?

Please note, I don't want to paginate eloquent, eg. User::paginate(10);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `Illuminate\Eloquent\Builder::paginate` method for an example on how to create one.

A simple example of doing one using an eloquent model to pull out the results etc:

```
$page = 1; // You could get this from the request using request()->page
$perPage = 15;
$total = Product::count();
$items = Product::take($perPage)->offset(($page - 1) * $perPage)->get();

$paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator(
    $items, $total, $perPage, $page
);
```

- The first parameter accepts the results to display on the page that you're on
- the second is the total number of results (The total number of items you're paginating, not the total number of items you're displaying on that page)
- the third is the number per page you want to display
- the fourth is the page that you're on.
- You can pass in extra options as a fifth parameter if you want to customise things as well.

The links you should just be able to generate using the `->render()` or `->links()` method on the paginator as you would if you used `Model::paginate()`

---

With an existing collection of items you could do this:

```
$page = 1;
$perPage = 15;
$total = $collection->count();
$items = $collection->slice(($page - 1) * $perPage, $perPage);

$paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator(
    $items, $total, $perPage, $page
);
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt quite full answer the question - "I have a collection. I wish to manually create a paginator." You are using offsets etc on a eloquent model.

Comment: Oh right, so does your collection contain ALL of the elements or is it a paginated list in itself?

Comment: @Jonathon, I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030097/how-to-add-some-textfield-in-form-register-laravel-generator-infyom

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Paginator like this:

```
$page = request()->get('page'); // By default LengthAwarePaginator does this automatically.
$collection = collect(...array...);
$total = $collection->count();
$perPage = 10;
$paginatedCollection = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(
                                    $collection,
                                    $total,
                                    $perPage,
                                    $page
                            );
```

According to the source code for LengthAwarePaginator (constructor)

```
public function __construct($items, $total, $perPage, $currentPage = null, array $options = [])
{
    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        $this->{$key} = $value;
    }
    $this->total = $total;
    $this->perPage = $perPage;
    $this->lastPage = (int) ceil($total / $perPage);
    $this->path = $this->path != '/' ? rtrim($this->path, '/') : $this->path;
    $this->currentPage = $this->setCurrentPage($currentPage, $this->pageName);
    $this->items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
}
```

> See more about [LengthAwarePaginator](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html)

To display links in the view:

```
$paginatedCollection->links();
```

Hope this helps!